# C# and HTML Code together in Razor View MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to achieve something like the following with MVC4 Razor Syntax. Here is the Code I am trying to write:

```
@{
    int counter = 1;
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @if (counter == 1)
        {
            <div class="section show">
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="section">
        }                                                
        <span>@counter <text> .</text> @Html.DisplayFor(ab => item.Title)</span>
        <div class="section-content">
            @Html.DisplayFor(ab => item.Description)
        </div>    
    </div>
    counter++;
    }
}
```

The above Code doesn't give any Compilation Error. But it causes Run time error. It says the Closing Tag is missing. Is it somehow possible to make the C# Code and HTML Code work together to achieve the result that I am trying to achieve here?

I am trying to get the C# Code and make them work based on Condition. For example, in the if Statement, if Counter is 1, the first div class will be selected and in rest of the times, the second div class will be selected.

Thanks. (I have updated the Question)

Comment: Please explain what it is you are trying to achieve. How can anyone tell you how to make the code "work" when you have not defined what "working" code is supposed to do?

Comment: No need to write `@` in `@{ ... }` block

Comment: I am trying to get the C# Code and make them work based on Condition. For example, in the if Statement, if Counter is 1, the first div class will be selected and in rest of the times, the second div class will be selected. @NightOwl888

Comment: I tried doing what you told also. But it always says it's missing the closing } character. @YuriDorokhov

Comment: try this <span>@counter <text> .</text> @Html.DisplayFor(ab => item.Title)</span>

Comment: I have tried what you suggested and updated my answer accordingly. Still it is saying the closing } is missing. Can you kindly tell me the reason for it. Thanks. @ssilas777

Comment: try changing @if (counter == 1) to if(counter == 1), its already inside a code block rit..

Comment: Thanks. It worked. :) @ssilas777

Comment: <span>@counter . @Html.DisplayFor(ab => item.Title)</span>, did this line worked without <text></text> node?

Comment: I used the <text></text> :) Thanks. @ssilas777

Comment: I asked because your accepted answer doesn't have that..it will create confusion. Thanks

Comment: I have edited that answer. It will be visible once it is reviewed. But I have said I did tweak on the answer a bit and I meant the thing that you mentioned. Thanks. @ssilas777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the if to create the div. Use it to determine the value of the class attribute:

```
    @{

    int counter = 1;   
    foreach (var item in Model)    
     {      
      result = "section";

         if (counter == 1)                                                
         {
             result = "section show";                                        
         }

     <div class="@result">
         <span>@counter <text> .</text> @Html.DisplayFor(ab => item.Title)</span>
         <div class="section-content">
             @Html.DisplayFor(ab => item.Description)
         </div>
     </div>
     counter++;
     }                                                                                    
 }
```

Comment: I did upvote the answer. But someone had downvoted it earlier. @user1739635